# Can Gedit plugins work in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: gedit, plugins, sublime-text

Is there a way to get the [gedit-dash](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/gedit-dash-new-tab-gedit-plugin-powered.html) plugin working in [sublime text2](http://www.sublimetext.com/)?

Here is a screenshot of gedit-dash

[image: gedit-dash]

Answer (score 1):

No. SublimeText2 and Gedit have their own plugin system, and while one could *port* a plugin to another API, their plugin API's are not the same interface.

Comment: I'll see that as a challenge. :)